# Jenkins version problem for string.replaceAll() in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, jenkins

In Jenkins i am using the CI/CD pipeline for the Node Project, In that i am using the function called string.replaceAll(), For this function the supporting version is above 15. In Jenkins I am using the version 16.14.0 but the API getting fails

In local machine the API its working with the version 16.14.0 with the same version is not working in Jenkins

I tried my solution like

1. changing the node version in the Jenkins global configuration 16.14.0
2. i also change the node version in the Docker file such as 15,16.17,18,19 but the API is still failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***To change the Node.js version in Jenkins, follow these steps:***

---

- Go to the Jenkins Dashboard.
- Navigate to "Manage Jenkins" on the left-hand side.
- Click on "Global Tool Configuration" from the available options.
- Look for "NodeJS" in the list of tools and click on it.
- In the NodeJS section, you will find a dropdown or combobox where you can select the desired Node.js version.
- Choose the desired Node.js version from the dropdown.
- Click on "Save" or "Apply" to save the changes.

By following these steps, you can update the Node.js version used by Jenkins for your builds and deployments. Remember to configure your Jenkins jobs to utilize the updated Node.js version if necessary.

> **If the desired Node.js version is not available in the dropdown, you**
> **might need to install it on the Jenkins server and configure it as a**
> **tool in the Global Tool Configuration section.**

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @tchrist it's not AI-generated output. Actively I'm working on CI/CD implementation in my project. I faced the same issues and solved them using these two ways. So I suggest a way to fix it.